# SQL QUERY complicated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

May anyone please help me how to get this.

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE
(
  LINE VARCHAR (50),
  SKU VARCHAR (50), 
  MAKE VARCHAR (50),
  MODEL VARCHAR (50),
  YEAR VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @MYTABLE
SELECT 'AIRFILTER','KNFHU-1200',    '629','23081',  '2013' union all
SELECT 'SERPTINBLT','TCI743812',        '99999',    '727',  '1972' union all
SELECT 'CAMSHAFT','DYC5060695', '51',   '575',  '1989' union all
SELECT 'CAMSHAFT','DYC5060695', '99999',    '575',  '1989' union all
SELECT 'HEADLIGHTB','COM08-443-8',  '47',   '458',  '1994' union all
SELECT 'ATTRNKCKCB','DTL03-1394',   '55',   '709',  '1992'


DECLARE @DRIVER TABLE
(
  Line VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @DRIVER
SELECT 'SERPTINBLT' UNION ALL
SELECT 'CAMSHAFT'
```

I would like to select those records whose make is other than '99999', whose `LINE` is given in the driver table.

for eg: two line available in the driver as "SERPTINBLT" and "CAMSHAFT"
so make for this two line should always be "99999", if it contain other than "99999", it should appear in the output
in this case line "CAMSHAFT" is present with two make that is "51" and "99999".

### **Expected Output**

```
CAMSHAFT|   DYC5060695| 51| 575|1989
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an *INNER JOIN* to filter rows by `@DRIVER` table, and use a *WHERE* clause to filter rows with the wrong `MAKE`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM @MYTABLE m INNER JOIN @DRIVER d
  ON m.LINE = d.Line
WHERE m.MAKE != '99999'
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple, You will have to use an`INNER JOIN` of the `@Driver` and exclude records which have make '99999' in `@Mytable`

Use the code below:

```
SELECT * FROM @DRIVER D
INNER JOIN @MYTABLE M
ON D.[Line] = M.[LINE]
WHERE M.[MAKE] <> '99999'
```

Comment: Why are you copying my answer (with mistakes)?

Comment: Are you serious??!!! 

Its a simple INNER JOIN not rocket science.... 
AND my answer is correct

Comment: A. I know it's not rocket science. Do you regularly go to already answered questions and add an already existing answer? B. It's not correct, since yours will have all columns of `@MYTABLE` **PLUS** all columns of `@DRIVER`, and that's not what is requested.

Comment: A. I did not copy your answer. I had the same in the edit and posted it.
B. Its the logic that the users require. The next user who is looking at this question, will not have the same column set.